# Scala - Enforcing a value

Tags: scala

(please note this is a simplified version of the actual problem )

Lets say you have `tag`, an `Int` that needs to be accessed statically in the following way

```
class Usage[T: universe.TypeTag](tag: Int) = {
    // use the tag in this class
    def realActualUsage(thingToBeSaved:T): Unit = { //...do stuff here 
       }
}

trait Tag {
    val customTag : Int 
}

class CustomTag(val irrelevantData:String, val irrelevantNumber:Int ) extends Tag

val useThis = new Usage[CustomTag](???) // <-- this is where I need my tag

// much later
useThis.realActualUsage(new CustomTag("Bla", 4))
```

as you see, there is a ??? where the `tag` (an Int) should go.
SO how to get this value??

#### Option 1

Given that CustomTag extends Tag you could implement the Tag trait and get the info you need from there like:

```
class CustomTag(val irrelevantData:String, val irrelevantNumber:Int ) extends Tag {
   override def customVersion: Int = 444
}
```

except you would need to create an instance of that class before using it in the ctor for `Usage`, this is not really the way that it should be so, that is not really going to work.

#### Option 2

You could also create a companion object for  where you register each of the versions of the Custom tags on a Map[Class, Int] but this option is not great either as you would have to manually register each class and that is something that is easy to forget.

#### Other option

The previous solution could work except it is error prone (it is easy to forget to register a custom version) and I  imagine there is a typed way to work this up, but I can't think of it.. also I imagine there is a bit of vocabulary /pattern missing as I search for this solution?

In response to @Jasper-M I need to be *able* to have a tag on all the sub-classes however I don't need to enforce it. I would like to suggest to the users of this that this is the place to do it if you need to.

Ideas welcome :D

Comment: Do you want to associate a different `Int` with every subclass of `Tag`? If not I'm totally lost as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: :D lol, apologies, not purposely obscure, I am sure there is a simpler way to ask the question... lets see if I can make the question more clear

Comment: So you can also call `new Usage[CustomTag]` without `CustomTag` having an `Int` tagged to it? Or do you mean that `CustomTag` doesn't *need* to have a tag, *unless* you want to create a `Usage[CustomTag]`?

Comment: I still don't understand how you want to use CustomTag without implementing customTag in it while you extends Tag Trait? Your compiler don't getting angry about it?

Comment: doesn't need a tag, however I would be ok if I had to provide one (as I can use a default)

Comment: wound up using implicit objects, need to add a solution here.